# iOS today extension always initiate the view

Tags: ios, today-extension

I have develop a iOS today extension, it will display some icons, when these icons change, the today extension will update. when these icons not changed, the today extension should not update. But i found my today extension view always be destoried, then re-initiated by system, so when i pull down the notification bar, my today extension alwayd flash caused by reload the icons. I want know, how to make today extension view not be destoried by system, i want my extension view not refresh when the icons not changed.

Thanks for rely.

Comment: you should provide some code you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the complete state of the widget and restore it in viewDidLoad?

That should keep it from flickering.